# Проблемы с Android Studio, jdk и sdk

Tags: android-sdk, android, android-studio

Недавно обновил Android Studio, и при создании нового проекта сразу же становится красным этот импорт:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

Из-за чего такое может быть? Переменные вроде все прописаны, пути указаны...
Но почему-то если в cmd посмотреть версию java, то он пишет _31, а в папке java у меня папка с названием jdk1.8.0_25, и папка с названием jre1.8.0_31. Т.е. почему-то разные версии.

**update**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hangover.admin.example15"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Comment: [это похожий вопрос][1]. должно помочь


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/399722/android-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-support-library

Comment: @arg для ссылки в комментариях используйте `[текст ссылки](ссылка)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено. Проблема как раз была именно в jdk. Я просто обновил jdk на 31 версию и прописал путь в студии на новую версию.

Answer (score 1):

1. В CMD показывает версию, на которую настроена система. Android Studio может использовать и другую. Нужно всего лишь указать путь.
2. Ваша проблема ***абсолютно*** не связана с JDK. Скорее всего, не подключена библиотека Appcompat.

Выложите свой build.gradle и откройте страшную тайну - на какую же версию вы все-таки обновились?

Comment: В вопрос выложил build.gradle. А как тогда подключить эту библиотеку?

Comment: Решено. Проблема как раз была именно в jdk. Я просто обновил jdk на 31 версию и прописал путь в студии на новую версию.